# Why does Ionic not use HTML5 elements (e.g. input, select, label)

Tags: html, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Why does the Ionic framework not make use of standard HTML5 elements like `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<label>`? Why does it define its own non-standard elements `<ion-*>` for everything except for `<button>`?

There are good reasons for reusing HTML5 elements instead of inventing new elements. What are the reasons for Ionic's approach?

The only reason I see so far is consistency between Ionic component names. Styling and native look can be achieved by replacing or wrapping standard HTML5 elements (this is what jQuery or third-party compoments do).

Comment: Presumably so that their CSS and JavaScript doesn't conflict with anything.

Comment: they are used own component you can use your project Ionic Component try this https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is so that these components look more native in each one of the platforms where they are executed in order to offer a better experience to the end user

> Ionic still uses an actual  HTML element within the
>   component, however, with Ionic wrapping the native HTML input element
>   it's better able to handle the user experience and interactivity.

[Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/)

Comment: Good reference, thank you. But native look and feel can also be achieved by styling, wrapping, or replacing standard HTML5 components.

Answer (score 0):

The future of web development is tending towards web components. ionic uses its custom  tags to achieve a more native look of the applications built using the framework.